# MassTransit - Failed to close scope

Tags: c#, asp.net, masstransit

I've got 2 ASP.NET api's running on the same instance of IIS, both use MassTransit on the same queue but for sending only.

On startup both api's create their own 'bus' queue however they seem to be colliding with each other somehow and eventually both bus queues will disappear and the same error will repeatedly happen every couple of hours:

```
ERROR - Failed to close scope MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer -rabbitmq://<host>/bus-DEV-API-w3wp-364yyynqbn68pfb5bdj5ic3kfr?durable=false&autodelete=true&prefetch=4
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer.<Stop>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MassTransit.Util.TaskSupervisorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<CreateParticipant>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Here is my configuration, this appears in Application_Start() of my WebApiApplication and is assigned to a public static variable:

```
        MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(new Uri(QueueEndpoints.HostBase), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
            cfg.UseLog4Net();
        });
```

Comment: Is your ASP.NET worker process being recycled at the same time as the error?

Comment: I don't think so as the error occurs even when the api hasn't received a request in over 24 hours

Comment: Any update? I'm facing the same issue right now.

Comment: I ended up changing some recycling settings in the Application Pool in IIS and that seemed to stop it.

Comment: Also: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/620

Comment: Also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/vOP5uwnNXls